# IOS: Document camera is not available

Tags: ios, swift, camera

Im trying to build simple camera app with apple's VisionKit, but faced Thread error while open camera.
I've added Privacy - Camera Usage Description to my info.plist
How can i get access to camera ?
I run app on emulator ? may this cause error ?

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import VisionKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func openCameraButtonTaped(_ sender: Any) {
        configureDocumentView()
    }
    
    private func configureDocumentView() {
        let scannerViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
        scannerViewController.delegate = self
        self.present(scannerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate {
    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinishWith scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
        for pageNum in 0..<scan.pageCount {
            let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: pageNum)
            
            print(image)
        }
        
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func documentCameraViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

info.plist:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires camera access to scan docs</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
```

Comment: At what line are you accessing the camera?

Comment: in method configureDocumentView() -> self.present(scannerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Nobody but you knows what VNDocumentCameraViewController is.

Comment: @ElTomato everyone who opened Apple docs knows what VNDocumentCameraViewController is.

Comment: @ El Tomato VNDocumentCameraViewController is native VisionKit object

Answer (score 2):

To test any camera related functionality you need to run app on a real device, simulator is not supported.